# Error CS1525 in Unity3D when using GameObject.AddComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to fix this error. The error itself is noted in the title above.
The rest of the code is fine and I do not need to insert. If you want the rest of the code inserted, let me know.

```
else if (this.item[this.itemSelected] == 10)
            {
                Ray ray7 = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                RaycastHit raycastHit7;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray7, out raycastHit7))
                {
                    if (raycastHit7.collider.name == "Window" & Vector3.Distance(this.playerTransform.position, raycastHit7.transform.position) <= 10f)
                    {
                        this.ResetItem();
                        Destroy(raycastHit7.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Material>());
                        raycastHit7.collider.gameObject.AddComponent<this.BrokenWindow>();
                        Destroy(raycastHit7.collider);
                    }
                }
            }
```

That's all the code.

I tried that code, and on the line where it says `this.BrokenWindow` the error occured.
`this.BrokenWindow` is a `UnityEngine.Material`. I was expecting for it to work and add the `UnityEngine.Material` component.

Comment: Please add the full error message copy/pasted from Unity to the question body.

Comment: Assets\Scripts\Assembly-CSharp\GameControllerScript.cs(453,71): error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'

Comment: Maybe should it be `AddComponent<BrokenWindow>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

T must be a Component **type**. It looks like BrokenWindow is a Material **reference**. Not only that you can't add a reference as a component, Material isn't a Component type.
[image]

If you want to change the material of the `raycastHit7.collider.gameObject`, you have to use a different approach, for example, through getting a Renderer's Material and then assigning the BrokenWindow Material to it.

For example, `raycastHit7.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = BrokenWindow`

Comment: Thanks! Also, note that I added `this.` to `BrokenWindow` since well.. yeah.